# Python removing items from list according to variable given

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
a=['I', 'O', 'O', 'I', 'I', 'O', 'O', 'I', 'I', 'U', 'U', 'I', 'I', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
```

I want to process the list so that

- `if a[0]=='I':` it would remove the next `'I'`
- `if a[0]=='O'` it would remove the next 3 `'O'`'s
- `if a[0]=='U'` it would remove the next `'U'`
- `S` and `X` don't do anything

and then `a[1]` ... until reaching the end

the result of a would be

```
a=['I','O','I','I','U','I','S','S','X','X','X','X']
```

it doesn't necessarily need to be the same list I can create another one.

Comment: Please don't use both [python-2.7] and [python-3.x] tags. If your question isn't specific to the version you're using, don't use either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 2):

first you want to loop until a[0] is 'X' or 'S'

```
while a[0] not in "XS":  # this will break if a is ever totally empty ...
   if a[0] == "I":
       a = takeNext(a,"I")
   elif a[0] == "O":
       a = takeNext(a,"O",3)
   elif a[0] == "U":
       a = takeNext(a,"U")
```

then all you have to do is write a takeNext method that looks something like

```
def takeNext(a_list,whatToTake,howManyToTake=1):
    #write this function
    #keep in mind you will also have to define some edge cases
    #what happens if the list doesnt have what you should remove
    #or only has 2 when you are supposed to take 3
```

keep in mind that this is a little bit over simplified there are several edge cases that do not have defined behaviour, based on your problem statement, so you will have to put some work in to define edge cases and their behaviour (I did include some examples of edge cases, but I make no claim that that is all the edge cases)